# What is the shortest way to get argument passed into program?

Tags: python

What is the shortest way to get argument passed into program. Shortest = at least count of characters. I need it because i do puzzles that requires arguments and it repeats in every puzzle. I use now `import sys`, but i'm not sure if it's shortest way.

```
import sys
a = sys.argv[1]
```

Comment: ? What kind of puzzles? Why do you care if the source code is short?

Comment: codercharts.com, some puzzles are rated by length of code. But code has to solve the problem, not to be only short ;)

Comment: @Miro: that's called code golfing, you might be interested in http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using tuple unpacking can shave one character

```
a=sys.argv[1]
_,a=sys.argv
```

and many more if you have more arguments

```
_,a,b,c,d,e,f=sys.argv
```

using `__import__` may shave one character if you're want to alias the import, although often this is not worthwhile than a plain import:

```
from sys import argv as v
v=__import__('sys').argv
```

Answer (score 0):

We can sandpaper off a few bytes:

```
import sys
v = sys.argv
```

Now you'll save seven characters every time you use `v[]` instead of `sys.argv[]`

Comment: Thx, but i know this. Also i use arguments only once at whole file. So that won't help me.

Comment: this could even be just one line: `from sys import argv as v`, but that's one character longer.

Comment: Can i get argv only using sys?

Comment: Nope -- without some kind of import, `sys` doesn't mean anything.